# Upgrading to iOS 15 causes production app icon to change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios15

I have updated my iPhone to iOS 15 and an icon for one of my production apps suddenly changed from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

I have launched the app from XCode 13 and still the same thing. I'm going to recreate the icons and reupload them, but any ideas before going through all that would be helpful.

N:B This happens on both the physical device and an iPhone simulator

Comment: File a bug report with Apple. Not us. Apple.

Comment: @matt, with you i'm not filing a bug report, i'm asking a question, the bug report has already been filed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just updated to iOS v15.0.1 and this **seems** to have resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

> Temporary solution - Restart the device after installing the app on
> device. AppIcon will then show up on dashboard.

It is already placed on [Apples developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682648).

Comment: Thanks for the response @DEX7RA, unfortunately, in my case, restarting the device yields the same result.

Comment: Did you delete your app, install it and THEN restart your device?

Comment: Yes i did, deleted it and installed from the App Store and restarted my device

Comment: Check if your icons exist in the assets folder. If yes, there is no other work around then reinstalling XCode or waiting for the next update that fix this. Hope I could help a little. Many people facing that error at the moment.